# Restricting number of continuous comma in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

how to limit the number of continuous 'comma' in a textbox?...ex it should not allow user to enter more than 2 comma continuously

Comment: Use Regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should handle most scenarios, I believe:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        int pos = tb.SelectionStart;
        int length = tb.Text.Length;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Replace(",,", ",");
        int diff = length- tb.Text.Length;
        tb.SelectionStart = pos == 0 || diff == 0 ? pos : pos - diff;
    }
}
```

This works when you type text into the `TextBox`, as well as when you paste text into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == ',')
    {
       if(TextBox.Text.Contains(",,"))
       {
           e.Handled = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to set `SuppressKeyPress = true`, rather than `Handled`, as described here in the Remarks section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled.aspx